# Getting 'TypeError: user is null' when trying to validate form using ember-cp-validations

Tags: javascript, validation, ember.js, ember-cp-validations

I am attempting to add form validation using [ember-cp-validations](https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-cp-validations) and am following the basic steps in their [video](https://embermap.com/video/ember-cp-validations) `TypeError: user is null` in the console. I am very new to ember and I am sure its something very basic I am overlooking.

**register-form component**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  user: null,

  actions: {
    save() {

      let user = this.get('user');

      user.validate()
        .then(({ validations }) => {

          if (validations.get('isValid')) {
            user.save();
          } else {
            alert("not valid");
          }

        });
    }
  }
});
```

**user model**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { validator, buildValidations } from 'ember-cp-validations';

const Validations = buildValidations({
  firstname: validator('presence', true),

  email: [
    validator('presence', true),
    validator('format', { type: 'email' })
  ],

  username: validator('presence', true),

  password: [
    validator('presence', true),
    validator('length', {
      min: 4
    })
  ]
});

export default DS.Model.extend(Validations, {
  firstname:  DS.attr('string'),
  email:      DS.attr('string'),
  username:   DS.attr('stirng'),
  password:   DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: You set the user as null. How you pass user to the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass new user to the component like this :

```
//routes/users/new.js
...
model(){
  return this.get('store').createRecord('user');
}
...
```

And in the template you put the register component do like :

```
//templates/users/new.hbs
{{register-form user=model}}
```

Comment: Thank you that did it. I will accept as the answer after the minimum time has passed.